# Trainable "Spam-Filter" for Images

Tags: image, algorithm, filter, spam, training-data

I remember a story about someone filtering images with a spam filter which he fed with some training data.

I come to the point where I exactly need something like this.

I have a lot different types of images (mainly people, e.g. selfies, group pictures, portraits, ..) but I only want **a certain type** (e.g. only male) of them. 
With the right algorithm and **training data** I think it's possible to get it to the point where I can pass an image to it and i get true or false whether it matches my type or not.

I had a look at a few Face/Gender Detection APIs, but none of them worked for me that's why I want to try the approach with the spam-filter - seems like a funny idea.

Here's what I need:

- a **trainable spam-filter** algorithm/code sample/API
- has to work offline
- preferably for **C#** or **Java**

I already spent a few hours trying different things and googling, now I'm here and I'd like to get your opinion on this problem and the solution you think is appropriate.

Buddha

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple image comparison algorithm that you can read about here: [compareImages php class](http://compareimages.nikhazy-dizajn.hu/).

Basically the way it works is this:

it takes an image (a cropped image would be best), scales it down to a 8x8 pixels image, converts it to a BW / Greyscale image, and then it calculates the mean value of the pixels (which is the average value).

Then it goes over all the pixels of the scaled image (64 pixels), and in every pixel where the pixel's value >= the mean value, it puts "1", and if the pixel's value < the mean value, it puts "0", resulting in a 64bit "signature" value of 0s and 1s.

This signature value is what identifies the image, and then you can save this signature value in some kind of a database, as your "learned" filter.

Then if an email arrives with some images.. you can just crop them, and scan them, produce a signature, and see if it matches any known signature in your database.

The good things about this algorithm are:

1. It is very fast and scalable (scaling an image down to 8x8 is fast, and scanning the pixels as described is fast too).
2. Because it converts the image to greyscale & resizes it down, it means it can detect any color variations or sizes of the same image.
3. Because you use 64bit signatures, it doesn't take alot of space in your database as well.

Hope this helps.